# Sending Google Talk and Facebook message via R with XMPP protocol

Tags: r, xmpp, rcpp

I personally wish to have a XMPP API for R, so that after time consuming simulation my R process may notify me on Facebook or Google Talk.

Email might be a choice, but I think it will be more convenient to notify the user through XMPP message in the future.

Is there any well known XMPP API for R?

Comment: with smartphones being so prevalent, you can also consider using service like http://boxcar.io/ which can send push notification to your device. For personal use it's free even. You can send notification from R using RCurl and boxcar's web api.

Comment: At some point it is just easier to give up on R and use `system()` to get an external program to do it.  I have a little python script that sends XMPP notifications and I just build a message string in R at the end of my job and the python sends it. Wheels. Invented once.

Comment: In my opinion, `system()` is only a solution for a specific environment, but a package will be a general solution for all R users. It is totally different.

Answer (score 1):

I myself write a toy XMPP Client for R named RMessenger (project: https://github.com/wush978/RMessenger , package: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11900271/Wush-R-pkg-src/RMessenger_0.1.tar.gz). The engine is a C library, libstrophe (http://strophe.im/libstrophe/), and I wrap it with Rcpp. So far it works on my machine and server (both Ubuntu). I tried to port it to windows, but failed. I am inexperienced to build Rcpp package on Windows.

This package only sends message to some XMPP service including facebook and google talk. Maybe I'll expand its feature such as sending attachment, or change the engine to google's Jingle++ (after understanding the License issue).

Answer (score 0):

I have published a R package, `RMessenger`, on CRAN to send Google Talk and Facebook message via R with XMPP protocol.

If you find a bug or want some new features, please discuss with me at https://github.com/wush978/RMessenger/issues.

Thanks